# Declare CSS stylesheet based on condition in controller

Tags: visualforce, css, conditional, variable

I have a Visualforce page which has a default CSS stylesheet declared, which is always used for general styling. What I would like to do, however, is have alternate stylesheets to change brand colours on the page depending on who the user is.

```
  <apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.DefaultCSS}" />
  <apex:stylesheet value="{!IF(<useBrand>,$Resource.CustomCSS_<myBrand>}" />      <!-- this line is where I don't know what to do
```

So in my controller I have the variables **useBrand** and **myBrand** (based on the User), and I need to get the matching stylesheet to use that brand's colour palette.

How would I declare the custom stylesheet? If there is no brand specific info on the user, then the 2nd stylesheet is not required as everything is in the default one. The 2nd stylesheet, if used, overwrites the colours from the default one. The name of the custom stylesheet will be the same for all, except for the suffix (**_myBrand**).

Is there a way to declare a stylesheet based on a variable in the page controller, and to build the name of the stylesheet using the variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out. I created a zip file with the smaller colour specific branding stylesheets, created one for the default colours too (so I don't have to do a condition). Here's what the result is, and it works perfectly.

```
  <apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.DefaulCSS}" />
  <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.CustomStyleSheets, brandStyle)}" />
```

**brandStyle** is a variable in my controller in which I put the stylesheet name (ie 'CustomStyleSheet_ABC.css').